# Twitter Boostrap using Blueimp Gallery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, blueimp

I have a simple html to display a gallery page. When I click on the images to start the gallery slideshow, only the first image is shown, the rest shows a black page. And I can't figure out why. Maybe there's something I might have missed out?

Here's my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />   
<title>Responsive Web Mobile</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/blueimp/blueimp-gallery.min.css">
<script src="js/blueimp/blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

 <h1>Gallery for my works</h1>

<div id="links">
    <div class="slides">
    <a href="img/1.jpg" title="1">
            <img src="img/thumbnails/1.jpg" alt="1">
        </a>
        <a href="images/2.jpg" title="2">
            <img src="img/thumbnails/2.jpg" alt="2">
        </a>
        <a href="images/3.jpg" title="3">
            <img src="img/thumbnails/3.jpg" alt="3">
        </a>

    </div>
</div>

<!-- The Gallery as lightbox dialog, should be a child element of the document body -->
<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls">
    <div class="slides">
    <a href="img/1.jpg" title="1" description="Description for Image 1">
            <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="1">
        </a>
        <a href="images/2.jpg" title="1" description="Description for Image 2">
            <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="1">
        </a>
        <a href="images/3.jpg" title="3" description="Description for Image 3">
            <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="3">
        </a>
    </div>
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <h3 class="description"></h3>
    <a class="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="next">›</a>
    <a class="close">×</a>
    <a class="play-pause"></a>
    <ol class="indicator"></ol>
</div>

<script>
    document.getElementById('links').onclick = function (event) {
        event = event || window.event;
        var target = event.target || event.srcElement,
        link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target,
        options = {index: link, event: event},
        links = this.getElementsByTagName('a');
        blueimp.Gallery(links, options);
    };
  </script>

  <script src="js/jquery.blueimp-gallery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/blueimp/demo.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So it was my own stupidity actually. I feel like throwing a punch at myself. My image link path in class links before my Gallery script was wrong.

Another wrong I did was to add images links in the slides div inside my Gallery script.

```
<div class="slides">
<a href="img/1.jpg" title="1" description="Description for Image 1">
        <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="1">
    </a>
    <a href="images/2.jpg" title="1" description="Description for Image 2">
        <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="1">
    </a>
    <a href="images/3.jpg" title="3" description="Description for Image 3">
        <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="3">
    </a>
</div>
```

Inside of my Gallery script. Please consider this closed.